# How to place e / after every menu button?

Tags: html, css

Ok, so I know there is a method of placing a " / " after every menu button by type it just once. I'm referring to this kind of menu.

Home / About / Portfolio.. so on ..

I know I could do it this way:

```
<li> <a href="#">Home /</a> </li>
<li> <a href="#">About /</a> </li>
```

But I want other way to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RTLdt/4/)

```
a:after{
    content: '/';
}
```

Avoid adding it to the last link, thanks Bjorn

```
li:last-child > a:after { 
    content: ''; 
}
```

Edit: 
it can be accomplish with one line too: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RTLdt/5/)**

```
li:not(:last-child) > a:after{
    content: '/';
}
```

Comment: Also, `a:last-child:after { content: ''; }` prevents that you end up with a / after the last item.

Comment: Bjorn great catch! I added the same functionality to my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/raviolicode/42p9v/)**

You may want a separator with borders:

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: fixed, I accidentally put fiddle.net instead of jsfiddle.net... Thanks!